# Is it possible to read the symbol table of a vmlinux file?

Tags: linux-kernel, elf

I'm trying to read the symbol table of linux kernel, vmlinux file, so far I tried `readelf`,

`readelf -s vmlinux`

But nothing got printed.

Listing all strings stored inside, with `strings` command, I could find symbol names like `sys_close`, so I guess there should be a solution that works.

**UPDATE**

I don't have the System.map, I think it's inside the vmlinux, otherwise how could you build the kernel module with exported names like `sys_close` ?

Comment: Did you build it with symbols attached?

Comment: nm -g /path/to/yourmodule.ko

Answer (score 0):

The kernel binary is a little bit different. Its symbols are located inside the System.map file, which sould be inside the same directory than the kernel (/boot).

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System.map) will give you more information about System.map.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do
objdump -t vmlinux
objdump -t vmlinux
Its same as readelf
Check your make file and look how vmlinux is prepared.
I am sure there are flags there.
Or post your makefile here